# Error on uploading CSV file as a raster

Tags: qgis, raster, csv, rasterization

I'm using QGIS 3.16.15 to import .csv data file using layer>add layer> add raster layer.
The data set have 3 columns (Northing, Easting, Elevation). All the data set have the same coordinate system (decimal points) but I keep getting an error only at random number but typically the y values. I have tried importing the data as a delimeter text layer but cant convert it to raster later (rasterize)
The error code when adding as a raster layer is:
Ungridded dataset: At line 3, too many stepY values Raster layer Provider is not valid.
example of the data set

[image]

could someone help me solve this error or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: What software are you using, and how?

Comment: im using QGIS 3.16.15. by importing the csv data file using layer>add layer> add raster layer.

Comment: please edit your question to clarify that; and add a QGIS tag.

Comment: thanks for providing feedback. i have edited the question

Comment: Load the data in as a delimited text layer then use the rasterize tool on the points

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE! The procedure is to import the CSV text file as a points vector layer and then regularize the grid. Everything can be done within QGIS, with the Grid process, which I can't say if it's available in version 3.16. In any case, it is very helpful to read the documentation of the gdal_grid command which is the one that runs under the hood: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html. If you would like to share the complete data we can see how to create the raster grid. Also some decisions (grid size, search distance and interpolation method) should be made by you.